# Как добавить значение каждому User'у Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Есть 1000 пользователей такого типа:

```
[{
"id": 0,
"name": "Alex",
"surname": "Smirnov",
"coins": 10,
"money": 0
},
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Paul",
"surname": "Tesla",
"coins": 15,
"money": 5
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Fernandez",
"surname": "Scott",
"coins": 13,
"money": 1
}]
```

Нужно добавить каждому пользователю новое значение с помощью Mongoose: "ban": false
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала нужно обновить `schema`, чтобы учитывалось поле `ban` (добавить поле), затем обновить данные в коллекции с помощью комманды `updateMany` (подразумеваю, что в коде есть место, где можно сделать вызов):

```
await MyModel.updateMany({}, { $set: { ban: false } });
```

где

- `MyModel` - название модели
- `{}` - условия выбора документов (filter)

[Источник](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating-using-queries)